# magento installation error "PHP extension "curl" must be loaded"

Tags: php, magento, installation

When i have installed, it shows the following error

```
    "PHP extension "curl" must be loaded." 
     Please set all required settings before clicking Continue
```

after the Localization step (ie.in configuration step)

i cant know how to fix it?
 plz help me guys! thanks in advance

Comment: are you on linux or windows??

Comment: @Sankalp Mishra i m using windows xamp server

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uncomment the following line: extension=php_curl.dll in the php.ini configuration file of your XAMPP/WAMP server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur guide guys! i have enabled this line "extension=php_curl.dll" in php configuration file in the php directory, Now it works well, thanks for ur helps once again

Comment: @DRAJI Remember to accept answers when they actually have helped you

Comment: @DRAJI To accep the answer click on right symbol in front of the answer.

Comment: Don't forget to restart apache server.

Comment: Of course restart apache after changing the file contents.

Comment: @Chiragit007: add LAMP... or maybe just remove XAMPP/WAMP... php.ini is just relevant.

Answer (score 4):

If you still can't resolve it even after uncommenting `extension=php_curl.dll`, here's a solution:

1. Click on `wamp` icon.
2. Navigate to php > php extensions.
3. Enable `php_curl` in the extension list.

Comment: How can I reach php extensions?

Answer (score 2):

There is PHP module php_curl, you need to enable it if you are installing it on local system.
This setting is in php.ini file. 
If you are on shared server, need to contact your Hosting Company. And if you have full server access just enable it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help, but i dont know how to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

enable the curl extensions in the folowing -- 
`php-pear.ini`, `php.ini`, and `php5.ini` in the php directory, 
and the `php.ini` in the `apache/bin` directory

By enabling i mean, uncomment the lines

And do not forget to restart Xamp server

Answer (score 1):

In **Ubuntu 16.04** default **PHP version is 7.0**, if you want to use different version then you need to install PHP package according to PHP version:

First of all Install CURL using this command:-

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

After that using these commands according to your PHP versions:-

```
1-> PHP 7.0: sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl    
2-> PHP 7.1: sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl    
3-> PHP 7.2: sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl    
4-> PHP 5.5: sudo apt-get install php5.5-curl
5-> PHP 5.6: sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for error “PHP extension “curl” must be loaded.” In Wamp server version 2.2 for Windows 7 (64-bit Operating System) ONLY.**

(Files to be Modified)

> php.ini file location: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\

```
php.ini file location: C:\wamp\\bin\php\php5.3.13
```

> phpForApache.ini file location: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\

Find extension=php_curl.dll using find command in notepad in all above mention ini file and Remove semicolon if there is and it should look like extension=php_curl.dll

```
Before (;extension=php_curl.dll) after (extension=php_curl.dll)
```

Now try reload your magento installation page where you got error of "**PHP Extension “curl” must be loaded**"
your will see no error :)

I hope it will work for you like worked for me, Thanks